# Changing file modification time to access time in bulk

Tags: linux, timestamps, touch, atime

I have a bunch of files in a directory where the modification time was changed (incorrectly) with `touch -m`

The access time of these files is still close enough to what the modification time was, so I'd like to change them back.

Is there a way of doing a `touch` where it sets the mtime = atime?  I don't want to set them all to the same timestamp, but I want to go file-by-file setting mtime = atime.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about:

```
#!/bin/bash

for file in *; do
    # Get the access time using stat
    dateString=$(stat --format %x "$file")
    # Use the datestring to update the time with the 
    # access time
    touch -d "$dateString" "$file"
done
```

From `man stat`:

```
   %x     time of last access, human-readable
```